Looping over form elements to insert into database
Cant figure out what I am doing wrong here, maybe someone here can help point out my issue.  I have a form that has about 240 form elements half of those form elements will insert into a database table via a CFC function from 1-120 and the other half will insert into the same table from 1-120.  The names of these elements are ALE 1 through 120 and the other half is CAD 1 through 120.  The problem is I get it to work all the way to ALE 1-115 before I get an error message which is where it stops.  Can anyone point out my problem here am I doing this wrong and maybe I should be doing this differently.  Thank you in advance.
<cffunction name="MyfunctionName" access="public" returntype="Any" output="false" hint="Inserts the ALECAD">
    <cfargument name="MAG_ID_1" type="any" default="">
    <cfargument name="MAG_ID_2" type="any" default="">
    <cfargument name="MAG_ID_3" type="any" default="">
    <cfargument name="MAG_ID_4" type="any" default="">
    <!---Loop the form elements--->
    <CFLOOP FROM="1" TO="120" INDEX="i">
        <CFPARAM NAME="Arguments.ALE#i#" DEFAULT="">
        <CFPARAM NAME="Arguments.CAD#i#" DEFAULT="">
    </CFLOOP>

    <cfset var InsertALECAD= "" />
    <cftry>
        <cftransaction >
            <cfquery datasource ="MydatasourceName" name="InsertALECAD">
                INSERT INTO MytableName
                                    (proj_no
                                    ,test_point_id
                                    ,TEST_TYPE
                                    ,MAG_ID_1
                                    ,MAG_ID_2
                                    ,MAG_ID_3
                                    ,MAG_ID_4
                                    <CFLOOP FROM="1" TO="120" INDEX="i">
                                        ,ALE#i#
                                        ,CAD#i#
                                    </CFLOOP>
                                    ,created_by
                                    ,create_date
                        VALUES
                                    (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#application.sanitizeData.recieveData(Arguments.proj_no)#" null="#IIF(Arguments.proj_no EQ "", true, false)#" maxlength="10"/>
                                    ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#application.sanitizeData.recieveData(Arguments.tpid)#" null="#IIF(Arguments.tpid EQ "", true, false)#" maxlength="20">
                                    ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="ALE-47" maxlength="15">
                                    ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#application.sanitizeData.recieveData(Arguments.mag_id_1)#" null="#IIF(Arguments.mag_id_1 EQ "", true, false)#"  maxlength="5">
                                    ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#application.sanitizeData.recieveData(Arguments.mag_id_2)#" null="#IIF(Arguments.mag_id_2 EQ "", true, false)#"  maxlength="5">
                                    ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#application.sanitizeData.recieveData(Arguments.mag_id_3)#" null="#IIF(Arguments.mag_id_3 EQ "", true, false)#"  maxlength="5">
                                    ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#application.sanitizeData.recieveData(Arguments.mag_id_4)#" null="#IIF(Arguments.mag_id_4 EQ "", true, false)#"  maxlength="5">
                                    <CFLOOP FROM="1" TO="120" INDEX="i">
                                        ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#application.sanitizeData.recieveData(trim(evaluate(evaluate(de("Arguments.ALE" & i)))))#"  maxlength="2">
                                        ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#application.sanitizeData.recieveData(trim(evaluate(evaluate(de("Arguments.CAD" & i)))))#"  maxlength="2">
                                    </CFLOOP>
                                   ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#application.sanitizeData.recieveData(Session.Auth.userid)#" null="#IIF(Session.Auth.userid EQ "", true, false)#" maxlength="10"/>
                                    ,GETDATE()
                                    )SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS New_ALE47_ID
            </cfquery>
            <cfquery name="fltdet" datasource="#application.dsn.name#">
                UPDATE  MyOtherTableName
                SET         ColumnName = <cfqueryparam value="#Val(1)#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BIT">
                WHERE       (ColumnName=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#application.sanitizeData.recieveData(Arguments.tpid)#" maxlength="25"/>)
            </cfquery>
        </cftransaction>
            <cfreturn True>
        <cfcatch>
            <cfinvoke method="errorHandler" argumentcollection="#ARGUMENTS#" />
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cffunction>


What does the error message say? And to which line does it refer? You have a couple of loops here.

Yes, we need to see the error message.

The error message I am getting is as follows: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'.s

Missing a closing ) before VALUES to close the column list.

Wow,  That worked.  I was hoping someone could figure out where my error was.  I didn't close the darn column.   Thanks.
